# How to force “Expression result unused” warning to happen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang

When I compile a statement `[[NSArray alloc] init];`, clang gives “warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]”.

How do I cause “Expression result unused” warnings from my own function? For example:

```
@interface SimplePromise : NSObject
-(SimplePromise*)then:(id(^)(id result))block;
@end

-(void)someMethod {
    // I want this statement to cause a warning because
    // the transformed promise is dealloc’d before the block ever executes!
    [self.fetchPromise then:^id(id result) {
        self.fetchedData = result;
        return nil;
    }];
}
```

Comment: I believe it only complains if it's an init method and it's not being saved in a variable or used by something else. In other words, you initialize something but don't do anything to keep a reference to it. It doesn't seem to complain for other methods that return values, and I don't think you can do anything to make it just simply show up for you. If you want to create your own warning, however, you can use `#warning` in your code.

Comment: It seems to me like you want a warning for a "return value result unused", right?

Comment: @Merlevede, yes, I want a warning if a specific method’s return value is discarded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare your method with `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`:

```
-(SimplePromise*)then:(id(^)(id result))block  __attribute__((warn_unused_result));
```